# Why is absolute time considered an axiom of Newtonian mechanics? What statements are based on this axiom?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spacetime, time, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

I guess absolute time is associated to classical mechanics because people like Newton believed in that concept, but are there actually any statements whose derivation is based on this assumption?

I've looked into the Noether's theorem and some proofs regarding the Lagrange equations and it didn't seem like this assumption was necessary.

Answer (score 14):

The concept of absolute time was perhaps more of a *postulate*, rather than an axiom.

If Newton's physics were based on any axioms, it would have to be the principle of relativity, which is perhaps the most profound concept, fundamental to his laws of motion. This principle was first stated by Galileo$^1$. It states that the laws of physics should be the same  in all inertial reference frames.

To this principle, Newton added his laws of motion, universal gravitation, and an *assertion* of an absolute time. He stated

"*Absolute, true and mathematical time, of itself, and from its own nature flows equably without regard to anything external, and by another name is called duration: relative, apparent and common time, is some sensible and external (whether accurate or unequable) measure of duration by the means of motion, which is commonly used instead of true time.*

So it is perhaps more accurate to not think of this absolute time as being based on an axiom, but rather a *postulate*, based on his (Newton's) understandings of space and time and other scientists understandings during that era.

$^1$ Newton's laws are invariant under Galilean transformations, described by the equations (for motion along the x-axis) $$x'=x-vt$$ $$y'=y$$ $$z'=z$$ $$\boxed{ t'=t }$$  Note that it becomes apparent that both Galileo and Newton (and others in that era) thought of time as absolute, encompassed in this last equation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In other words, absolute time was just a common missbelieve at that time, but the mathematical formulation of the theory is not based on this assumption?

Comment: Yes, it was believed to be true and the formulation of his laws of motion were based on this.

Comment: @josephh: I don't know why you keep making comments that suggest you wish absolute time is not needed in Newtonian mechanics. The additivity of velocity **fails completely** in Einstein's theory of special relativity, which has been empirically verified so far. Since Newtonian mechanics proves the additivity of velocity, **obviously** it is due to the assumption of absolute time, since other assumptions used in that proof are okay.

Comment: @user21820 "_you keep making comments that suggest you wish absolute time is not needed in Newtonian mechanics_" What? I actually suggest the complete opposite. Perhaps you meant this for someone else?

Comment: Really sorry, it was meant for @Filippo. I don't know how I failed to ping correctly.

Comment: no worries. It seemed obvious that you mistakenly tagged me. Cheers.

Comment: @user21820 "I don't know why you keep making comments that suggest you wish absolute time is not needed in Newtonian mechanics" - As I already said, I have studied some of the Lagrangian formalism and it seemed like many important proofs - e.g. the invariance of the Lagrange equations under point transformations and the Noether theorem - work without the assumption of Galilean transformations. I initially put "classical mechanics" in the title, but a moderator replaced it by "newtonian mechanics".

Comment: @josephh Thank you for adding the remark on the invariance of Newton's laws under Galilean transformations, I think that's possibly the most important point.

Comment: @josephh I personally would find it remarable if my claim that the Lagrangian equations are invariant under a larger class of transformations is actually correct

Comment: You're right and your quite welcome. Cheers.

Comment: @Filippo: I don't even know what you mean by "Lagrangian formalism", and very likely you are mistaken in your claim. The main issue is that isolated equations are devoid of meaning. You can only ascribe meaning to a formalization as a whole; a set of equations governing some aspects of physics (e.g. mechanics) only has meaning as part of an overarching formal system. Hence wikipedia has an article about [relativistic Lagrangian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics). Such an article would be superfluous if it wasn't affected by the assumption of absolute time.

Comment: @user21820 "I don't even know what you mean by 'Lagrangian formalism', and very likely you are mistaken in your claim" From what I know, a typical course on classical mechanics would be divided into three parts "Newtonian mechanics", "Langrangian mechanics" and "Hamiltonian mechanics".

Comment: I am only (a little bit) familiar with Lagrangian mechanics and when I looked into the proof that the Lagrange equations are invariant under point transformations (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3198368/572841)), it seemed to me that the proof also works for a more general class of transformation - transformations where also the time transforms, e.g. by a strictly monotonous function. This made me wonder where exactly the assumption of Galilean transformations comes into play in classical mechanics.

Comment: @Filippo: So what you are missing is precisely what I stated in my previous comment. That is, there are some mathematical theorems regarding partial derivatives. A priori, they have absolutely nothing to do with physics. You need **interpretation** to even claim that they assert something about "mechanics". Precisely when you do so, your interpretation is *forced* to be based on *other* assumptions. For instance, if you want to interpret some coordinate as "time", you necessarily make assumptions about what "time" *satisfies* otherwise it remains meaningless. [cont]

Comment: [cont] In particular, why call a coordinate "time", and not "mass" or something else? It's because you *already* have in mind some **structure** in which time is a feature and satisfies some properties. Without any such real-world structure in mind, all the quantities in a mathematical theorem have no real-world relevance. You also cannot make predictions involving "time" without some preconception of it, including how to measure it. The assumption of absolute time is baked into all predictions that implicitly assume different observers share temporal coincidence.

Comment: In short, while a mathematical theorem that is used in physics may not depend on assumptions about the real world, all applications of that theorem to physics may depend on many assumptions to be even meaningful, not to say allow you to make reproducibly accurate predictions, which is the hallmark of good science.

Answer (score 12):

Newton and others did not think necessary to state that the time was absolute (at least not as a postalate$^1$), because they considered this self-evident. Indeed, if they doubted this, they would have come with something similar to (special) relativity much earlier.

I think the assumption about absolute nature of time is most obvious when deriving Galilean transformations as opposed to Lorentz transformations (I mean the pedestrian derivations where one adds velocities). You get the former one, assuming that the time is absolute, and the latter, assuming that the speed of light is constant.

**Example: addition of velocities**
As an example of a statement based on the absolute time we can take the addition of velocities. The position of an object in reference frame B is given by
$$
x_B(t) = x_A(t) + X(t),
$$
where $X(t)$ is the position of the origin of reference frame A. Assuming that the time is the same in the two reference frames, we can differentiate this equation, obtaining:
$$
v_B = v_A + V
$$

---

1 But see the Newton's quote in @josephh answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was expecting someone to come up with Galilean transformations - could you please name a reference where I can find the type of derivation you have in mind? I'd look to look go through the proof and understand exatly on what assumptions it is based.

Comment: It is usually covered in basic mechanics courses, as addition of velocities - perhaps even Holliday&Reznik have it, but on elementary level. Wikipedia suggests Arnold's *Mathematical methods of classical mechanics*. Essentially, the positions in different reference Frames are related by $x_B(t)=X(t)+x_A(t)$ and one differentiates it in respect to time to obtain velocity addition - thsi already implies that time is absolute. Lorentz transformations are discussed in a similar way the introductory texts on special relativity (in more advanced texts they may be derived from symmetries).

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out!

Comment: "Newton and others did not think necessary to state that the time was absolute" — except Newton _did_ bother to state this in _Principia_, as mentioned in joseph h's answer.

Comment: @JacobManaker they didn't state is as a postulate, the quote given by joseph h is valuable, and I upvoted their answer long ago. I also clarified my answer.

Comment: @Arthur thanks, I made it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Absolute time means there is unique procedure to determine which events are simultaneous and this is present everywhere in Newtonian mechanics.

Take for example third Newton law. It states, that if object A acts on object B with some force, so does the object B on object A with force equal in magnitude and opposite in direction. But if the force is changing as system evolves, how do we know when exactly is the reaction force to be applied? The answer is, at the same time. I.e. there is an assumption that "at the same time" has absolute meaning, otherwise two different observers would assign reaction force at different events.

> I've looked into the Noether's theorem and some proofs regarding the Lagrange equations and it didn't seem like this assumption was necessary.

How so? In newtonian mechanics, one demands Lagrangian to be invariant under Galilean transformations. These transformations do not transform time coordinate, so absoluteness of time is present right there in the symmetries of Lagrangian. I.e. if you start with list of all possible Lagrangians of Newtonian mechanics and find out their symmetries, you will notice that there is a class of coordinate transformations that keep all of them invariant and that these transformation can be used to define special kind of time. So it is there.

Comment: "otherwise two different observers would assign reaction force at different events" I don't understand, can you elaborate, please?

Comment: @Filippo Imagine both objects A and B have their own clocks. Then if object A acts on object B by some force at certain time of B's clocks, two different observers would not agree at which time of object's A clocks should they assign the reaction force.

Comment: What do you mean by "assigning" the reaction force?

Comment: @Filippo at which time the reaction force acts.